# Window title in X shows wrong application name

Tags: bash, terminal, window-title

I am using LXDE environment in Debian, but I think my question is general.
When I have a window opened (i.e. terminal emulator running bash) the window has a window title with the text `/bin/bash`. When I start `mc` in the terminal, the title changes to `mc [martin@localhost]`.

The same text also appears as the window name on the window panel, where I can switch between opened windows.

My problem is, the window name does not refresh, it still shows `mc [martin@localhost]`, even when I am already logged on another machine. Only when I start `mc` does the title refresh again.

Is there a way to make the title refresh automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs set the window title and forget to reset it before terminiation.

You can add something like the following lines to your '~/.bashrc' to set the window title before each new bash prompt.

The case statement makes this happen only on terminals known to be capable of changing the window title with an ESCape command. I suggest to add 'screen*' there...

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

These lines come from a '/etc/bash.bashrc' of Debian-6.0.9 and initially are commented out there. Look into your system's '/etc/bash.bashrc', you probably will find some similar lines in there.

The default '~/.bashrc' may contain similar lines. If you do not want to activate this system wide, do it there instead by uncommenting or adding these lines.

When you already are using `PROMPT_COMMAND`, put the case statement after your preexisting `PROMPT_COMMAND` definition and write the assignment inside the `case`statement like:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;"'echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
```

Comment: this works great! Just wondering, what are the characters `\033]0;` and `\007` for ? And why do I need `echo` ?

Comment: I have just noticed, `PROMPT_COMMAND` was already set in my `.bashrc`: `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r"`. What happens if I use your code? Will I loose my previous settings?

Comment: `\033` is ESCape, the rest is selecting the desired terminal command and passing parameters to it. Have a look at [ctlseqs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).